# Dynamic Tag Insertion Not Working on Windows IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I am dynamically inserting html tags into the document using the following strategy. It works on Mac Chrome and Firefox but not on Windows IE or Windows Firefox. I suspect this has something to do with the angle brackets in the string assigned to the innerHTML property of the newly created div tag. Any ideas?

```
function addElement() {

      var ni = document.getElementById('stateSet');
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      var divIdName = 'state'+ stateCount;
      stateCount++;
      newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
      newdiv.innerHTML = '<input id="name" type="text"/> <input id="setting" type="text"/><button type="button" >x</button>'
      ni.appendChild(newdiv);

    }
```

Comment: you dont need a `type` for a button element

Comment: where is `stateCount` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring statecount

```
function addElement() {
  var stateCount = 0;
  var ni = document.getElementById('stateSet');
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  var divIdName = 'state'+ stateCount;
  stateCount++;
  newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
  newdiv.innerHTML = '<input id="name" type="text"/> <input id="setting" type="text"/><button type="button" >x</button>'
  ni.appendChild(newdiv);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TPx3v/